# Android (Java) file upload to PHP servar fails with Android 4.03

Tags: php, android, file-upload

We have, with good result, used a script for a game of ours that connects to a php-file in order to upload files to a remote server. When we upgrade to Android 4.03 the script suddenly fails to connect to the server and we have no clue why. It works very well with Android 2.3.4 and older.

```
public static String uploadOrderFile(Context c) {
String error = "";

HttpURLConnection conn = null;
DataOutputStream dos = null;
DataInputStream inStream = null;
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

String exsistingFileName = String.format("orders%d.ser", empire.getId());
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
String responseFromServer = "";

try {
    //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
    // Opening streams.
    if(settings.isSaveToExternalStorage()) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), String.format("%sorders%s.ser", c.getString(R.string.pathExternalStorage), empire.getId()));
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    }
    else {
        fileInputStream = c.openFileInput(exsistingFileName);
    }

    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
    String s = c.getString(R.string.webPageOrders);
    URL url = new URL(s);
    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    // Allow Inputs
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Allow Outputs
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    // Don't use a cached copy.
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    // Use a post method.
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(String.format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"%s\"%s", exsistingFileName, lineEnd));
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    // create a buffer of maximum size
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // read file and write it into form...
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    error = "Error. Couldn't find the order file internally.";
    Log.e(TAG, error, fnfe);
}
catch (MalformedURLException murle) {
    error = "Error. Couldn't create correct file URL.";
    Log.e(TAG, error, murle);
}
catch(ProtocolException pe) {
    error = "Error. Couldn't upload the order file to server.";
    Log.e(TAG, error, pe);
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
    error = "Error. Couldn't upload the order file to server.";
    Log.e(TAG, error, ioe);
}
finally {
    try {
        // Closing streams and connections.
        if(fileInputStream != null) {
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
        if(conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        if(dos != null) {
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        error = "Error. Couldn't disconnect internet stream buffers.";
        Log.e(TAG, error, ioe);
    }
}
if(!error.equals("")) {
    return error;
}
//Reading the server response.
try {
    inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
    String str;
    while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
        responseFromServer += str;
    }
}
catch (IOException ioe){
    error = "Error. Couldn't read server response.";
    Log.e(TAG, error, ioe);
}
finally {
    try {
        // Closing streams.
        if(inStream != null) {
            inStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        error = "Error. Couldn't disconnect internet stream buffers.";
        Log.e(TAG, error, ioe);
    }
}
return error;}
```

On the server we have the following PHP-file:

```
<?php

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "orders/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "orders/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

  echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
    chmod ("orders/".basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']), 0644);

} 
else{

echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
echo "target_path: " .$target_path;

}?>
```

Any help with this problem is appreciated. Why does it fail with Android 4.03 whan it works flawlessle with previous versions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
class getEditingHUD extends AsyncTask<String, Long, Integer> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(HtmlViwer.this, null,
                "Please wait...");
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "yourfile.html");
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            String myserver = "http://your server/phpfile.php";
            HttpFileUploader htfu = new HttpFileUploader(myserver,
                    "noparamshere", Modules.currentProgram + ".html");
            htfu.doStart(fis);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error Readingfile", e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            if (loading != null && loading.isShowing())
                loading.dismiss();
        } catch (Throwable t) {

        }
    }

}
```

and this HttpFileUploader class

```
public class HttpFileUploader implements Runnable {

URL connectURL;
String params;
String responseString;
// InterfaceHttpUtil ifPostBack;
String fileName;
byte[] dataToServer;

HttpFileUploader(String urlString, String params, String fileName) {
    try {
        connectURL = new URL(urlString);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i("URL FORMATION", "MALFORMATED URL");
    }
    this.params = params + "=";
    this.fileName = fileName;

}

void doStart(FileInputStream stream) {
    fileInputStream = stream;
    PrakitoServer();
}

FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

void PrakitoServer() {
    String exsistingFileName = "print.html";

    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    String Tag = "3rd";
    try {
        // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

        Log.e(Tag, "Starting to bad things");
        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) connectURL
                .openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos
                .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                        + exsistingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        Log.e(Tag, "Headers are written");

        // create a buffer of maximum size

        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        int maxBufferSize = 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // close streams
        Log.e(Tag, "File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        // retrieve the response from server
        int ch;

        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
            b.append((char) ch);
        }
        String s = b.toString();
        Log.i("Response", s);
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

call the uploadOrderFile method in AsyncTask class . you will fix it

for AsyncTask class refer this link
[How to execute some code in Android UI thread async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173299/how-to-execute-some-code-in-android-ui-thread-async/9173455#9173455)

Comment: Hi @prakash! It didn't help. At the moment we use the following code to call on our uploadOrderFile:

Comment: 'final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "","Uploading orders. Please wait!", true); new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { String error = uploadOrderFile(getBaseContext()); dialog.dismiss(); return; } }).start();'