# Impossible to update the text of a textview in a RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, textview

I have a simple screen created in xml, the parent layout is a "relativelayout" and i have a child layout (who is also a "RelativeLayout" containing 3 textview inside).

the only thing I have to do is press a button and change the values ​​of textviews.

to change the text is obviously this:

```
MyTextView.SetText("Text");
```

the code runs perfectly, but does not refresh the text of the textviews in the layout.

**but when the screen is rotated, the screen refreshes, and the label gets the correct value.**

Why does this happen? Why when pressing the button I can not update the text?

I tried using "AsyncTask" and the text is not updated either.

Did something simple can be so problematic. ?

greetings.

Comment: plz show some of ur code.........

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restoring state of TextView after screen rotation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179686/restoring-state-of-textview-after-screen-rotation)

Comment: the "layout" is not updated/refreshing after assigning the text to a textview why? I tried to update a "textview" which is "outside" of the layout and updated fine. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
MyTextView.SetText("Text");
```

Should be executed on UI thread to give effect say suppose if you want it to be updated after button click then this code should be inside your `onClickButton` listener  of your button

Visit [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173299/how-to-execute-some-code-in-android-ui-thread-async) for more details

Comment: Hi, I know that, but here the problem is that I can not update the text of a TextView inside a layout, I tried to update the text of a TextView that is "outside" the layout and it works fine, why?

Comment: the button is inside a AlertDialog.

Comment: You can use just Dialog and add the content to it having your own button and then you can prevent it from closing dialog and close dialog whenever you want. :)